# How can i display object into data table using material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is my object

```
[{
  "Element": 
  [
    {
      "name": "Hydrogen",
      "position":1,
      "symbols": [{"symbol": "H","Weight": "1.5"}]

    },
    {
      "position":2,
      "name": "Helium",
      "symbols": [{"symbol": "He",  "Weight": "3.2"}]
    },
    {
      "position":3,
      "name": "Lithium",
      "symbols": [{"symbol": "Li","Weight": "9.2" }]
    }
 ]
} ]
```

i want to display the above object into datatable i tried here but its not showing data

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnuh4v-jn562v?file=app/table-filtering-example.ts)

its showing empty table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is wrong you are using array inside array and accessing it as a plain object

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol[0].symbol}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Modified data :

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] =
  [
    {
      "name": "Hydrogen",
      "position": 1,
      "symbol": [
        {
          "symbol": "H",
          "Weight": "1.5"
        }]

    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "name": "Helium",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "symbol": "He",
          "Weight": "3.2"
        }]
    },
    {
      "position": 3,
      "name": "Lithium",
      "symbols": [
        {
          "symbol": "Li",
          "Weight": "9.2"
        }]
    }];
```

Updated **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cnuh4v-zqdzys)**

Comment: i want above data to be displayed in data table is it possible??

Comment: can you visualize what is the expectation?

Comment: @thecool have a look at this [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-igifuu) hope that helps. if so update the post with the relevant information so I can update the answer

Comment: you should be passing that as input to the dialog hope you will continue from there